# problem with arm_navigation stack

Tags: ros, move-arm, arm-navigation, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!!

I have a problem with arm_navigation stack.
I need to get a trajectory with target time, in other words, I want a path that executed in that time.
The MotionPlanRequest message, that it inside move_arm_action, has two parameters for to defined path duration. But, the result trajectory time is smaller that target time.

Any ideas??

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28604/problem-with-arm_navigation-stack/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

None of the planners we release really plan for dynamics, so while they are part of the message those values are not used.  If the problem is that the resulting trajectories are too fast, that should be pretty easy to fix - just increase the times on the trajectory points before you send the path to the controller.  At least the PR2 controller should be able to act correctly based on that.  If the paths are too slow there's not that much that can be done about that - you can potentially increase the acceleration limits in the joint_limits.yaml file and move the arms somewhat faster.  Finally, the right way to do this is have the planner reason more about timing, but that's not something our planners currently do.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1